# Usage of importlib.import_module to replace from m import v

Tags: python, python-import, python-importlib

Does anyone know what is the equivalent of

```
from modulename import var
```

if I wanted to use import_module

[importlib.import_module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html)

Answer (score 0):

The following works

```
_tmep = importlib.import_module(modulename)
var = _temp.var
```

Or in one line as:

```
var = importlib.import_module(modulename).var
```